# Why is stdClass namespaced?

Tags: php, namespaces, stdclass

> Argument 1 passed to nms\aclass::__construct() must be an instance
>   of nms\stdClass, instance of stdClass given

The `__construct()` function looks like `public function __construct(stdClass $aclass)`

And I get the error, I am passing in an instance of stdClass from the global namespace, not one from within the same namespace,

I also get the solution: `public function __construct(\stdClass $aclass)`

But what I don't get is **why**? I don't think it is even possible to overwrite stdClass is it? so would what is the difference between `\stdClass` and `\nms\stdClass`?

Comment: When you have already declared a namespace i believe anything used with that file/class is assumed to be within that declared namespace. Thus to use something in the global you need to explicitly reference it with `\ `.

Comment: Unless your class is doing something incredibly generic, I would question the value of typehinting a `stdClass`. Surely you know enough about what kind of object you're expecting that you can give it a more useful typehint?

Comment: basically it's inside code igniter, What the class is expecting is the results from a database query, Which CI returns as a `stdClass`, basically, the typehinting here is because if it's not an object that is passed in then someone has messed up and has passed through an empty result set or a query that failed or similar, it's more rudimentary error checking than anything else. regardsless this is more a generic question than about the `value` of typehinting stdClass!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it's possible to override `stdClass` inside of a namespace.

```
namespace Example;

class stdClass {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "Overridden!";
    }
}

$global = new \stdClass();
$local = new stdClass;
```

Outputs:

```
Overridden!
```

---

Hence, if you want the original, you'll need to use the `/stdClass` global namespace. Much like with `/Exception`s.

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought it would give you a lovely `Cannot redeclare class stdClass in `... error! but no, thinking about it, that's the purpose of namespaces!

Comment: @Hailwood: Indeed it is. Even native functions can be redeclared from inside of a namespace.